# Updating a table by using if condition - PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here am trying to update a field in a table with two values if the value which i got from other file using the GET function is Deactivate update the value of cnf_status as 1 and if it is Activate update the value of cnf_status as 0. But this bit of code is not working...can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$status = $_GET['status'];


if($status == Deactivate)
{

mysql_query("update user_details set cnf_status='1' where user_id = '$id'");
}
else if($status == Activate)
{
mysql_query("update user_details set cnf_status='0' where user_id = '$id'");

}
?>
```

Comment: Whant does 'not working' means? Provide your error

Answer (score 1):

Forgot quotes maybe?

```
if($status == "Deactivate")
{
  mysql_query("update user_details set cnf_status='1' where user_id = '$id'");
}
else if($status == "Activate")
{
  mysql_query("update user_details set cnf_status='0' where user_id = '$id'");
}
```

You should also consider using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid SQL Injections.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you dont use Single quotes for Int fields... try removeing them.
You only need them when using with fields like: text, varchar, enum

Also you should quote the Deactivate & Activate otherwise they will be used as constants

Comment: Yeah, i know. Actually i took out the quotes just to get see whether any changes happens. But not changes. Now i tried again by adding quotes, its not working even now

Comment: you have a mysql connection set up? try this at the end: echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";